# How to replace different categorical variables with another list of categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with categorical values as [0 1 2 3 4 5]. I want to replace these values with only [1 2 3 4] in the following manner:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
0,4,5 -> 3
```

excel categorical map

[image]

I tried this code:

```py
bins = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, np.inf]
names = ['4','1','2','3','4']
data['NEW_EDU'] = pd.cut(data['EDU'], bins, labels=names)
```

But I get- 
ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to use [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
df.loc[df['EDU'].isin([0,4,5])] = 3
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'EDU': [1,2,3,4,5,0,4,2]
})
```

Output:

```
    EDU
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   0
6   4
7   2
```

Use

```
df.loc[df['EDU'].isin([0,4,5])] = 3
```

Output:

```
EDU
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   3
4   3
5   3
6   3
7   2
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way using a lambda expression:

```
df['NEW_EDU'] = df['EDU'].apply(lambda x: 3 if x in [0, 4, 5] else x)
```

Or using numpy.where:

```
import numpy as np
df['NEW_EDU'] = np.where(df["EDU"].isin([0, 4, 5]), 3, df["EDU"])
```

If, as @rafaelc suggests, it's important to keep the column as a categorical type:

```
df['NEW_EDU'] = pd.Categorical(np.where(df["EDU"].isin([0, 4, 5]), 3, df["EDU"]))
```

Comment: This will also change the `dtype` from category to int, not intended. Also, why use `apply` if you have vectorized options at hand? ;)

Comment: Yep it's slow but it's an option! Numpy.where is another faster alternative.

Comment: Honestly, the apply method is awful. It is slow and not readable, not to account for the fact that you have to create a lambda function *and* inside that lambda you "search" in a list (could've at least used `3 if x in {0,4,5} else x` instead to search on a `set`. But the `np.where` option is beautiful, readable and pretty efficient so congrats on that one! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to map the new values to the keys:

```
value_dict = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 0:4, 4:4, 5:4}
```

Then iterate through the column and replace the keys with the mapped values.

```
df['NEW_EDU'] = [value_dict[x] for x in df['EDU']]
```

This lets you create arbitrary mappings between a list of values

Comment: This will also change the `dtype` from category to int, not intended

Comment: Could just use map: `df['NEW_EDU'] = df['EDU'].map(value_dict)`

Comment: @rafaelc what's a 'category' `dtype`? It's either an `int` or `str`.

Comment: @AdarshChavakula Take a look at `df.dtypes` before and after :)

Comment: Can also refer to some more info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/arrays.html#api-arrays-categorical)